# Anchor Tags to Simple Jquery Accordion to activate specific tab & position

Tags: jquery, html, accordion

I am mainly having an issue getting the anchor tag link to land on a centered position of the accordion content pertaining to a particular tag now.

Js:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();

    $('.accordion > dt > a').click(function() {
        allPanels.slideUp('normal');
        $(this).parent().next().slideDown('normal');
        return false;
    });

    $(location.hash).show();

});

</script>
```

Updated HTML:

```
  <dl class="accordion">

  <dt><a href="">Panel 1</a></dt>
  <dd>Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.</dd>

  <dt><a name="">Panel 2</a></dt>
  <dd>Donec nec justo eget felis facilisis fermentum. Aliquam porttitor mauris sit amet orci. Aenean dignissim pellentesque felis.</dd>

  <a name="#reviewpoints" style="">&nbsp;</a>  
  <dt><a name="#reviewpoints">Panel 3</a></dt>
  <dd id="reviewpoints">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Phasellus hendrerit. Pellentesque aliquet nibh nec urna. In nisi neque, aliquet vel, dapibus id, mattis vel, nisi. Sed pretium, ligula sollicitudin laoreet viverra, tortor libero sodales leo, eget blandit nunc tortor eu nibh. Nullam mollis. Ut justo. Suspendisse potenti.</dd>

  </dl>
```

Link on seperate page:

```
<a href="/points/#reviewpoints">Review Points Test</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update on your fiddle:

```
(function($) {

  var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();

  $('.accordion > dt > a').click(function() {
    allPanels.slideUp();
    $(this).parent().next().slideDown();
    var hash = location.href.split("#")[1];
    $(location.hash).show();
    return false;
  });

})(jQuery);
```

**Fiddle: http://jsbin.com/reyosobifa/1**

Comment: You can use `location.hash` instead of `location.url`

Comment: @jcubic Thanks. Updated.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll give it a shot now.

Comment: @JasonElliott Sure... Make sure you add jQuery and wrap it up everything inside `$(document).ready()` function.

Comment: `    $(document).ready(function() {
         (function($) {
    
      var hash = location.href.split("#")[1];
    $("#" + hash).show();
    
      $('.accordion > dt > a').click(function() {
        allPanels.slideUp();
        $(this).parent().next().slideDown();
        return false;
          });

    })(jQuery);
    });
`

Comment: I have a basic understanding of it. I just want to make sure I have it right.

Comment: @JasonElliott I can't read what you have commented. Please add it in your question. Thanks.

Comment: I made a quick fix but it doesnt seem to work when the hash is loaded with the url.

Comment: @JasonElliott Try using the second version, which has `location.hash`?

Comment: I've add the html and js details in the question.

Comment: @JasonElliott Check out the updated answer and if it works, please accept it. `:)`

Comment: It works, but two problems...  when I get to the hashed url the anchored tab doesnt open automatically. second a click on a tab opens, closes then opens again.

Comment: @PraveenKumar can you view that link

Comment: @JasonElliott Please use `jQuery` instead of `$`.

Comment: @JasonElliott Did you replace all `$` with `jQuery`.

Comment: If you view the same link you will see that it opens twice on one click

Comment: basically figured out that the slide up variables needed 'normal' in the parenthesis I'll updated the working code